# Issue while adding addCatch to fargate inside step function

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I am trying to add addCatch to a fargate task running inside step function using aws cdk Typescript Custom State.

```
new CustomState(this, "Failed", {
      stateJson: {
        Type: "Fail",
      },
});

const stateJson = {
  Type: 'Task',
  Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync',
Retry: [
        {
          ErrorEquals: ["ECS.AmazonECSException"],
          IntervalSeconds: 2,
          MaxAttempts: 6,
          BackoffRate: 2,
        }
      ],
      Catch: [
        {
          ErrorEquals: ["States.All"],
          Next: "$.Failed",
          ResultPath: "$.error",
        },
      ],
  Parameters: {
   LaunchType: "FARGATE",
        Cluster: clusterName,
        TaskDefinition: TaskDefinition,
  },
  ResultPath: '$.FargateOutput',
};

const custom = new sfn.CustomState(this, 'my custom task', {
  stateJson,
});

const chain = sfn.Chain.start(custom)
  .next(finalStatus);

const sm = new sfn.StateMachine(this, 'StateMachine', {
  definition: chain,
  timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
});
```

But during deployment I am getting error *Invalid State Machine Definition: 'MISSING_TRANSITION_TARGET: Missing 'Next' target: $.Failed*

Comment: Hi. I do not see "Next" in Catch method:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask.html#addwbrcatchhandler-props

Comment: Have you managed this case? I have absolutely the same case and can't find any way to add catch state to ecsRunTask one.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this myself and stumbled upon your question. I'm not using the ecs resource but am using a CustomState with CDK and was encountering the same error.

What I got to work was the following...

```
Catch: [
    {
      ErrorEquals: ["States.All"],
      Next: "Failed",  // just use the ID of your CustomState as-is
      ResultPath: "$.error",
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is still an [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/25798) with cdk and one that I ran into as well.

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to solve this using a CustomState but I did manage to create an [EcsRunTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask.html) state, which provides an [addCatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask.html#addwbrcatchhandler-props) method.

All of the props you specified in the CustomState have corresponding props in EcsRunTask.