# How do I modify parameters in a Container Overrides section of a Step Functions machine?

Tags: json, typescript, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

I have a Step Functions Machine the definition file of which looks as such:

```
                          "ContainerOverrides": [
                            {
                              "Name": "Foo",
                              "Environment": [
                                {
                                  "Name": "Foo"
                                  "Value": "Bar"
                                },
                              ],
                              "Command.$": "States.Array($.Foo,$.Foo,$.Bar,$.Bar,$.Bar)"
                            }
                          ]
                        },
```

that I am trying to rewrite into Typescript (CDK). I've gotten the following few lines.

```
      containerOverrides: [{
        containerDefinition: Foo,
        environment: [
          { name: 'Foo', value: 'Bar'},
        ],
        command: ['States.Array($.Foo,$.Foo,$.Bar,$.Bar,$.Bar)'],
      }],
```

I'm a bit confused about how to go about this.

When I deploy the above CDK code, I get as output:

```
                            "Command": [
                     "States.Array($.Foo,$.Foo,$.Bar,$.Bar,$.Bar)"
                            ],
```

My confusion is in regards to the following: The ContainerOverrides method doesn't accept parameters, but I need to modify a parameter (Command.$), so how can I possibly do that? I came across this [post](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/21242/) where somebody seems to have a similar issue, but when I try to apply the proposed solution, of simply writing

`command: JsonPath.arrayAt('States.Array($.Foo,$.Foo,$.Bar,$.Bar,$.Bar)'`

I get told that ''Cannot use JsonPath fields in an array, they must be used in objects''

Comment: Which CDK task construct are you using?

Comment: @fedonev I'm using an EcsRunTask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** The current implementation of `EcsRunTask` doesn't permit this. The general-purpose [CallAwsService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.CallAwsService.html) construct does.

---

The `EcsRunTask` construct is the CDK's implementation of the [ECS optimised integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html). The construct only accepts an array of strings as override commands. It cannot produce substitutable output like `"Command.$": "$.commands"` that's needed to read the override command from the execution input. This is a limitation of the CDK implementation, not of the ECS optimized integration itself.

The cleanest solution is to use the `CallAwsService` construct, which implements the [SDK service integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html). It requires manual configuration.  The API-specific config goes in the [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.CallAwsService.html#parameters) prop.  The prop is loosely typed as `{ [string]: any }`.  It's flexible, but it's your job to provide the [expected syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html) for the `ecs:RunTask` SDK call.  Here is the relevant bit for your question:

```js
parameters {
    Overrides: {
        ContainerOverrides: [
            { Command: sfn.JsonPath.array("sh", "-c", sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.cmd")), },
        ],
    },
}
```

It produces the expected command override in the Step Functions task definition:

```json
"Command.$": "States.Array('sh', '-c', $.cmd)"
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful, thanks for sharing. I've tried the CallAwsService construct, and it works perfect. Is there anyway to still add the .sync integrationpattern that was available with the EcsRunTask? My issue is that I need both command.$ parameter to be overridden and the state to have a .sync integration pattern.

Comment: @DevBob Glad to help.  Unfortunately, the SDK integrations [do not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-services.html#connect-to-services-integration-patterns) the `.sync` pattern.

Comment: @DevBob If you really need the `.sync` pattern, I think your best option is a [CustomState](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions-readme.html#custom-state) construct to pass arbitrary State Machine JSON.  It's for cases such as yours where the CDK constructs are overly restrictive.

Comment: Thank you, I'll get back to experimenting with this later. For now, it seems to implement the `.sync` pattern, but struggles with follow up states in the ``Catch`` field akin to what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036062/issue-while-adding-addcatch-to-fargate-inside-step-function), as I got the same issue of 

_Invalid State Machine Definition: 'MISSING_TRANSITION_TARGET: Missing 'Next' target: $.Foo_ despite the follow up state being present in the catch field, and it needing to exit otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate an extra step then you can use step_function_tasks EvaluateExpression to build your command array and pass that directly to EcsRunTask:

```
create_command_builder_task = tasks.EvaluateExpression(scope, 'Build CLI command',
        expression="""[
            'sh',
            '-c',
            $.Foo,
            $.Foo,
            $.Bar,
            $.Bar,
            $.Bar
        ]""",
        result_path="$.Command"
)
```

Then use JsonPath.list_at to retrieve the Command:

```
tasks.ContainerOverride(
  command=step_functions.JsonPath.list_at('$.Command')
)
```

Then:

```
StateMachine(scope,
        'StateMachine',
        definition_body=step_functions.DefinitionBody.from_chainable(create_command_builder_task.next(ecs_task))
        )
```